# How can I get round ytick values in TikZ/pgfplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm new in TikZ/pgfplotting. I'm not understanding why I'm getting these `x,xxx,999` values instead of round `x,xxx,000` values. I've tried changing the `ymax`, `ymin` values several times but failed. Also `ytick={}` is not helping either. What can I do to represent these datas perfectly?

```latex
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{import}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
        scaled ticks=false,
            yticklabel style={
                   /pgf/number format/.cd,
                      fixed,
                     precision=0,
                    fixed zerofill,
            /tikz/.cd},
            every tick label/.append style={font=\small},
            }

\begin{figure}    
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
\begin{axis}[
    legend style={font=\fontsize{7}{5}\selectfont},
    xtick={0,5,10,...,50},
    %ytick={2238000,2239000,...,2247000},
    xmin=0,
    xmax=50,
    ymin=2238000,
    ymax=2247000,
    xlabel=Trials (n) $\rightarrow$,
    ylabel=Total Cost (\$) $\rightarrow$,
    grid=both,
    minor grid style={gray!25},
    major grid style={gray!25},
    width=0.9\linewidth,]
\addplot[blue] table [x=a, y=c, col sep=comma] {./Datas/40_unit_50_trials.csv};
\addlegendentry{Total Costs at Trials}
\addplot[red] table [x=a, y=c, col sep=comma] {./Datas/avg_40_unit_50_trials.csv};
\addlegendentry{Average Total Cost}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Your code cannot be made compilable because not may have the data files.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Try `/pgf/number format/.cd,relative*={3},precision=0,relative style=fixed` instead.  See the "Number printing" section of the [pgf manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, xmax=50,
xtick distance=5,
ymin=2238000, ymax=2247000,
scaled ticks=false,
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd, relative*={3}, relative style=fixed, 1000 sep={\,}},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Empty graph with large y tick labels]

Comment: +1: Necromancer :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Thanks - normally my answers to old questions has zero votes and is not accepted. I am trying to answer one old question with PGFPlots tag every time I close three.